# Raptor tool-Ubuntu version

Tags: software-installation

Can someone please help me download raptor flowchart tool for saucy salamander via terminal? (If this is repeated, I'm sorry)

Comment: What exactly are you talking about?

Comment: Follow this link [Raptor on Ubuntu linux | TestingDocs.com](https://www.testingdocs.com/running-raptor-flowchart-on-ubuntu/)

Answer (score 1):

RAPTOR (Rapid Algorithmic Prototyping Tool for Ordered Reasoning) flowchart tool has a bronze rating in the [WineHQ Applications Database](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=24239). It is stripped of some features in Ubuntu. The same link also has the URL of the RAPTOR home page which has a link to download RAPTOR.

If you want to try an alternative to RAPTOR that runs natively in Ubuntu, take a look at draw.io desktop application for creating diagrams. The drawio snap package can be installed in Ubuntu 18.04 and later with this command:

```
sudo snap install drawio
```

[image]